# Rearranging partitions

Tags: ubuntu, filesystems, partition, partition-table

[image: Ubuntu disk]

How can I use the 500Gb of free space?
I deleted Windows, and now there is a big gap of space, which I can't use.

`/` Isn't big enough for an update, but I can not move it without un-mounting it, which isn't possible.

How would I go about moving `/` and `/boot`?

Comment: You probably don`t need a separate `/boot` partition. This was done a lot when hardware could not boot on a partition that went past some block number (e.g. large than 512MB).

Comment: You can move /home. To move /home uses rsync- Be sure to use parameters to preserve ownership & permissions 
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Partitioning/Home/Moving Or you can use it as a data partition and mount some data from /home in it. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1013677/storing-data-on-second-hdd-mounting & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1058756/installing-all-applications-on-a-ssd-disk-and-putting-all-files-on-hdd-disk  Or do a new install rearranging partitions as you want. In all cases have good backups.

Answer (score 2):

Boot using https://www.system-rescue.org - run startx, run GParted, do what you want :-)

I strongly recommend making backups prior to everything.

Answer (score 2):

A less risky option that moving and resizing partitions. (However in your case re-sizing `home` may be more risky, but you could use a 3rd partition).

- Create a big `/home` partition.
- Move some parts of `/` to `/home`, and sym-link to them.

Candidates to move to `/home`

- I have done these

  - `/usr/local` and `/opt`, because you want to keep them when you re-install, but them may be small or even empty.
  - `/var/cache/apt/`, because it can get big, and does not need to be on `/`
- Others that should work

  - `/usr`, not need to got from boot to mounting, and is very big.

In the long term, I would reduce the number of partitions. I see no need (in most cases) to have more than `swap`, `/` and `/home`.